# why not a lua implementation of google's protocol buffers? is there already any better solution exist for lua?

Tags: serialization, lua, protocol-buffers

why not a lua implementation of google's protocol buffers? is there already any better solution exist for lua?

Comment: Maybe no one has gotten around to write one yet?

Comment: i don't think so. i saw a guy plan to do this but stoped but another guy in the google group of protobuf; and lua is already a data description language as the manual claimed, so i think may be there is a better way to do the same thing in lua besides protobuf, but i don't know how, and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on it as we speak: https://github.com/haberman/upb/wiki

Also, I'm the guy who wrote the 100-line parser above.  But my upb library is much more full-featured.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a Lua implementation of protocol buffers [lua-pb](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-pb).  It dynamically loads/parsers .proto files to create message objects, so there is no dependence on the standard .proto compiler from Google.

It uses [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html) for parsing .proto files and [struct](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/) & [Lua BitOp](http://bitop.luajit.org/) for encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because a C or C++ implementation would be faster (and easier to write), and then you could hand the data off to Lua to be used if you want.

There's a 100 line C protocol buffer parser here: http://blog.reverberate.org/2008/07/12/100-lines-of-c-that-can-parse-any-protocol-buffer/

Or you could just use the Google C++ one, and then hand your data off to Lua from there.

Lua isn't built for bit twiddling, so perhaps that's why nobody has implemented protocol buffers in it yet. It doesn't even have bitwise operators built in: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Lua 5.2 now comes standard with `bit32` for bit twiddling.

Comment: Lua 5.3 introduced C-like bit operators that work on 64 bit internal integer representation.